# DI and transclusion

Tags: angular

I have three components where `componentC` appears as content of `componentB` and gets `componentB` DI'ed in its constructor.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'componentA',
  template: `
    <componentB>
        <componentC></componentB>
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    </componentB>`
....
export class ComponentC {
    constructor(private cmpB: ComponentB)
```

Now I use `componentA` from another component and want to use transclusion to supply additional `componentC`s to it via the `<ng-content>` that I put in `componentA`'s template:

```
<componentA>
    <componentC></componentC>
</componentA>
```

This triggers a `No provider for ComponentB`. Using `<ng-content>`, I defined that the content should appear inside `<componentB>` so DI should be able to find the `ComponentB` object that is the parent of the insertion point.

Is this scenario possible? Does Angular create my extra `ComponentC` directly at the target location or first where the markup is then moves it? Is there a way to configure providers to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The transclusion doesn't make `componentC` a child of `componentB`, it stays a child of `componentA`, just where it is shown within the DOM is changed.

I don't see an easy way to make the injection work.

You could make `componentA` provide a service where `componentA` assigns a reference to `componentB`

```ts
@Component({
  ...
  providers: [ComponentBProviderService],
class ComponentA {
  @ViewChild(ComponentB) componentB:ComponentB;
  constructor(private bProvider: ComponentBProviderService){}
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.bProvider.component = this.componentB;
  }
}
```

When `ComponentC` injects this service it will get access to `componentB`.
It would make sense to use an `Observable` in the service, to actively notify `componentC` when the reference becomes available.

```ts
class ComponentC {
  componentB:ComponentB;
  constructor(bProvider: ComponentBProviderService){
    bProvider.componentAvailable.subscribe(val => this.componentB = val);
  }
}
```

Comment: Good point about transclusion not changing the component hierarchy but just moving DOM stuff around.

Would there be another solution using a template and a component factory to instantiate the content as a child of `componentB`?